# How to calculate backpropagation through tf.while_loop to use as loss function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to implement an Fourier Ring Correlation Loss for two images to train a GAN. Therefore I'd like to loop over a specific amount of times and calculate the loss. This works fine for a normal Python loop. To speed up the process I want to use the `tf.while_loop` but unfortunately I am not able to track the gradients through my while loop. I constructed a dummy example just to calculate gradients during a while loop but it doesn't work. First, the working python loop :

```py
x = tf.constant(3.0)
y = tf.constant(2.0)

for i in range(3):    
    y = y * x

grad = tf.gradients(y, x) 
with tf.Session() as ses:
    print("output : ", ses.run(grad))
```

This works and gives the output

[54]

If i do the same with a tf.while_loop it doesn't work:

```py
a = tf.constant(0, dtype = tf.int64)
b = tf.constant(3, dtype = tf.int64)

x = tf.constant(3.0)
y = tf.constant(2.0)

def cond(a,b,x,y):
    return tf.less(a,b)

def body(a,b,x,y):

    y = y * x 
    with tf.control_dependencies([y]):
        a = a + 1
    return [a,b,x,y]

results = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [a,b,x,y], back_prop = True)

grad = tf.gradients(y, results[2])

with tf.Session() as ses:
    print("grad : ", ses.run(grad))
```

The output is :

> TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type '<'class 'NoneType'>

So I guess somehow tensorflow is not able to do the backpropagation.

The problem still accours if you use tf.GradientTape() instead of tf.gradients().

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code so that it now outputs the gradients:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(0, dtype = tf.int64)
b = tf.constant(3, dtype = tf.int64)

x = tf.Variable(3.0, tf.float32)
y = tf.Variable(2.0, tf.float32)
dy = tf.Variable(0.0, tf.float32)

def cond(a,b,x,y,dy):
    return tf.less(a,b)

def body(a,b,x,y,dy):

    y = y * x 
    dy = tf.gradients(y, x)[0]
    with tf.control_dependencies([y]):
        a = a + 1
    return [a,b,x,y,dy]

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as ses:
    ses.run(init)
    results = ses.run(tf.while_loop(cond, body, [a,b,x,y,dy], back_prop = True))
    print("grad : ", results[-1])
```

The things I modified:

1. I made `x` and `y` into variables and added their initialisation `init`.
2. I added a variable called `dy` which will contain the gradient of y.
3. I moved the `tf.while_loop` inside the session.
4. Put the evaluation of the gradient inside the body function

I think the problem before was that when you define `grad = tf.gradients(y, results[2])` the loop has not run yet, so y is not a function of x. Therefore, there is no gradient.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. That kind of helps but doesn't solve my real problem. In my case:


x : is the output of my model.


y : is my loss


and I want to addapt my model to optimize y regarding the model's output x so I need to access the gradient outside of the while loop.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just upgraded to tf2 and replaced the while loop with a python for loop. Fortunately, tf2 has AutoGraph and optimizes for speed automatically. With python for loops I had no issued getting the gradients for my loss.